# Too many SOQL queries 50001

Tags: soql, class

I am getting an error of Too many SOQL queries 50001 in my schedule class.Can you suggest where am I going wrong?

```
global class update_Account implements Schedulable    
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {
    Map<Id,Account> AccountToChangeRequest=new Map<Id,Account>([Select id,name,lastname,(Select Id,Updated__c,Lead_Merchant_Name__c,New_Value__c,Additional_Comments__c,Request_Type__c 
    from Change_Requests__r where Updated__c= False  and Lead_Merchant_Name__c!= NULL order by LastModifiedDate asc)from Account]);
    List<Account>AccountToBeUpdated=new List<Account>();
    List<Change_Request__c> changerequestToBeUpdated=new List<Change_Request__c>();

 Account acc;
 Change_Request__c ncr;
    for(Id i:AccountToChangeRequest.keyset()) 
    { 

         if(AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r.size()>0)
         {
            acc=new Account(id=i);
            for(Change_Request__c cr:AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r)
            { 
                ncr=new Change_Request__c(id=cr.id);
                if(cr.Request_Type__c=='First Name')
                {
                    acc.firstname=cr.New_Value__c;
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;
                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='Last Name')
                {
                    acc.lastname=cr.New_Value__c;
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;
                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='Alternate Email')
                {
                    acc.Alternate_Email__c=cr.New_Value__c;
                    system.debug('--acc.Alternate_Email__c--->>'+acc.Alternate_Email__c);
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;
                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='Phone')
                {
                    acc.Phone=cr.New_Value__c;
                    system.debug('--acc.Phone--->>'+acc.Phone);
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;

                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='Alternate Phone')
                {
                    acc.Alternate_Phone__c=cr.New_Value__c;
                    system.debug('--acc.Alternate_Phone__c--->>'+acc.Alternate_Phone__c);
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;

                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='Industry')
                {
                    acc.Industry=cr.New_Value__c;
                    system.debug('--acc.Industry--->>'+acc.Industry);
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;

                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='Website')
                {
                    acc.Website=cr.New_Value__c;
                    system.debug('--acc.Website--->>'+acc.Website);
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;

                }
                else if(cr.Request_Type__c=='PersonMailingCity')
                {
                    acc.PersonMailingCity=cr.New_Value__c; 
                    system.debug('--acc.PersonMailingCity--->>'+acc.PersonMailingCity);
                    ncr.Updated__c=true;

                }


                changerequestToBeUpdated.add(ncr);
            }
            AccountToBeUpdated.add(acc);   
        }
    }    
            system.debug('--AccountToBeUpdated--->>'+AccountToBeUpdated);
            system.debug('---changerequestToBeUpdated-->>'+changerequestToBeUpdated); 
            if(!AccountToBeUpdated.isEmpty())
            update AccountToBeUpdated;
            if( !changerequestToBeUpdated.isEmpty())
            update changerequestToBeUpdated; 


   }

}
```

Comment: Move your logic to a batch...the error seems pretty clear. Your combination of `Account` and `Change Request` records totals more than 50k rows.

Comment: Each sub query counts as an additional query and count of records for the purpose of governor limits. Query  all account in scheduler class and in batch execute method write [select id ,(inner query where accountid in :scopelist) from account where id in :scopelist]. Move your business logic into batch execute method

Comment: It's the query rows limit being hit, not number of queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use limit statement in query to avoid hitting governor limit... The modified query should look like-

```
Map<Id,Account> AccountToChangeRequest=new Map<Id,Account>([Select id,name,lastname,(Select Id,Updated__c,Lead_Merchant_Name__c,New_Value__c,Additional_Comments__c,Request_Type__c 
    from Change_Requests__r where Updated__c= False  and Lead_Merchant_Name__c!= NULL order by LastModifiedDate asc limit :Limit.getLimitQueryRows())from Account limit :Limit.getLimitQueryRows() - Limit.getQueryRows())];
```

Calling `Limit.getLimitQueryRows()` will return maximum number of rows can be queried. Calling `Limit.getQueryRows()` will return current usage.

Answer (score 0):

Code needs to be moved to Batch class to process chunks of records for each iteration of batch . Moreover, ensure where clause is properly optimized with indexed fields.